# ScrollChangeListener for scrolling up android

Tags: android, webview

i just implemented ScrollChangeListener in my webview , when user scroll the webview .The toolbar should hide, this is how i did (or i got from internet but it works)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
         mEulaContent.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {


                 ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();


             }


         });

     }
```

then i want , when the user scrolls the webview up, it should show the toolbar
like

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
```

plz help me

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
         mEulaContent.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
             @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {


                // ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

                 if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                     ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

                 }
                 if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
                     ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
                   //  Log.i(TAG, "Scroll UP");
                 }

                 if (scrollY == 0) {
                     ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
                 }
             }


         });

     }
```